# Installing ggplot2 after installing rtools

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package, rtools

I'm trying to install the package ggplot2 on R but it gives me a warning saying that I have to install Rtools. I did it, but it still gives me the same warnings saying that I have to install Rtools. What do I have to do after installing Rtools? And what do you mean by restarting R studio? Just close the session? this is the warning message:

```
  install.packages("ggplot2")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘gtable’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.1              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
gtable     0.3.0  0.3.3             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.0              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.1  0.6.1              TRUE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.4.2             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1569486 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8QvApK\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘gtable’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtable_0.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 130057 bytes (127 KB)
downloaded 127 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3153811 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'gtable' ...
** package 'gtable' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gtable'
* removing 'C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/gtable'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gtable’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'gtable' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8QvApK\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: This isn't referring to the Rtools package, it's referring to the Rtools for Windows you can get from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/ (click on "Download R for Windows", then "Rtools"; sorry, the linking is terrible)

Comment: RTools is only needed if you need to compile the package from source. For `R 4.2.x`, it can be downloaded from this link https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html

Comment: To be clear: download and then install Rtools, it sounds like you've done this. Now you need to completely restart R and RStudio for the change to be seen.

Comment: If you let that run to completion, do you actually get an error? What is the full output?

Comment: I posted the whole output I get after trying to install the package

Comment: Looking at your message, it's indicating the wrong `rlang` package version is being installed.  Try `install.packages("rlang")` first, then try `install.packages("ggplot2")`.

Comment: I tried to install the package rlang first but it still doesn't work. What can I do?